# Matlab dot index error in array filled with objects from a class

Tags: arrays, matlab, class, oop

Hi everyone i'm experiencing some trouble with my code. The goal is to add multiple objects to a class, i've created the following code for that:

```
array = cell(1,10);
A = matrix %specified somewhere else
for ind = 1:10
   [r c] = find(A<3);
   random = randi([1, size(r,1)]);
   array{ind} = classname(1, r(random), c(random));
end
```

This block of code does everything I want it to, however, later on I add this array as property to another class and have to work with that specific array to make changes to it. And that is where is goes wrong.

```
function growing(thisElement)
  for i = 1:length(otherClass.array)
    range = range((otherClass.array(i).locationX - 2), (otherClass.array(i).locationX +2));
    if otherClass.array(i).pos<20
      ......
    end
  end 
end
```

Whereby both locationX and pos are properties of classname. I get the error *Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.* For both the range as the last if part. The error is apparently very commen error, however, I don't find any answers relating my case. Has anyone an idea to bypass the error?